# Django Rest Framework get data from related table

Tags: python, django

I have a database table of `cards`, and this has a relationship with another table of `sets` that those cards belong to. The `Cards` tables has a foreign key, `set_id` which links the two tables togethers. When I return the the card data, I am struggling to return the related data for the sets the cards belong to.

**models.py**

```py
class Set(models.Model):
    id   = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    
    ...

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Card(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    
    ...

    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cards', related_query_name='cards')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def manaCostList(self):
        a0 = self.manaCost.replace('//', '{//}')
        a1 = a0.split('{')
        a2 = [s.strip('} ') for s in a1]
        a3 = [s.replace('//', 'slash') for s in a2]
        a4 = [s.replace('/', '') for s in a3]
        a5 = list(filter(None, a4))
        return a5
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class SetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = '__all__'

class CardSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cards = SetSerializers(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['cards', 'manaCostList']

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        expanded_fields = super(CardSerializers, self).get_field_names(declared_fields, info)

        if getattr(self.Meta, 'extra_fields', None):
            return expanded_fields + self.Meta.extra_fields
        else:
            return expanded_fields
```

In my JavaScript when I perform a `console.log(b)` there is no data from the `Sets` table.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `cards` field should be defined in `SetSerializer` instead.

Comment: I tried to change it around but could not get it to work I'm afraid. Could you please explain what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. I have replace `cards = SetSerializers(many=True, read_only=True)` with `setCode = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="set.code")`.

This adds a single field, called `setCode` from the parent table to the response.

```py
class CardSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    setCode = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="set.code")

    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['setCode', 'manaCostList']

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        expanded_fields = super(CardSerializers, self).get_field_names(declared_fields, info)

        if getattr(self.Meta, 'extra_fields', None):
            return expanded_fields + self.Meta.extra_fields
        else:
            return expanded_fields
```